# Scraping in Python - How to get the bullet points on this site

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the following bullet points on this website. Would greatly appreciate help with the solution.

Website: https://underdognetwork.com/basketball/nba-news-and-fantasy-basketball-notes-6-10

For example I would like to only scrape the following bullet points:

```
Stephen Curry (foot) — In
Robert Williams (knee) — Available
Otto Porter (foot) — In
Robert Williams (knee) — Available
Stephen Curry (foot) — In
Otto Porter (foot) — In
Andre Iguodala (knee) — Available
James Wiseman (knee) — Injured
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try as follows:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://underdognetwork.com/basketball/nba-news-and-fantasy-basketball-notes-6-10'

resp = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'lxml')

info = [p.get_text() for p in soup.select('li > p')]

print(info)

['Stephen Curry (foot) — In',
 'Robert Williams (knee) — Available',
 'Otto Porter (foot) — In',
 'Robert Williams (knee) — Available',
 'Stephen Curry (foot) — In',
 'Otto Porter (foot) — In',
 'Andre Iguodala (knee) — Available',
 'James Wiseman (knee) — Injured']
```

To get rid of the duplicates, use `list(set(info))`. If you want to preserve order, have a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-i-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-while-preserving-order).

Comment: Thank you for providing this solution so quickly! It works - have a great day.